# Remove rows that contains at least one duplicate value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of indexes A :

```
A = np.array([[1, 4, 3],
              [1, 2, 5],
              [6, 7, 8],
              [9, 10, 2],
              [11, 3, 12]])
```

I would like to delete each lines that contains at least one duplicated value (no matter in which column it's located) to obtain an array with no duplicates indexes :

```
[[1, 4, 3],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 2],
```

Is there a quick and convenient way to perform this ?

Comment: @not_speshal--my guess is because of the 3 in the first row i.e. [1, 4, 3].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that no sub-list should be in the output if a value in it has already been in any previous sub-list then one possible solution can look like this,

```
# Assuming that A is a 2-D list
output = []

# Add all values to a set
st = set()
for i in range(len(A)):
  for j in range(len(A[i])):
    if A[i][j] not in st:
      st.add(A[i][j])

for i in range(len(A)):
  flag = True
  j = 0
  while j < len(A[i]):
    if A[i][j] not in st:
      # set flag to false if value not in set meaning a duplicate is encountered
      flag = False
      break
    else:
      # if a value is in the set then remove it from set 
      st.remove(A[i][j])  
    j += 1  
  
  # append A[i] to output only if the sub-list did not encounter any duplicates 
  if flag:
    output.append(A[i])
```

The time complexity will be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

When the input is,

```
A = [[1, 4, 3],
     [1, 2, 5],
     [6, 7, 8],
     [9, 10, 2],
     [11, 3, 12]]
```

It provides the output,

```
[[1, 4, 3], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you it's a good work around and O(n²) should be fine !
However I would like [9, 10, 2] to still be present because [1, 2, 5] will be removed because 1 is duplicated.
Then [9, 10, 2] will be the first appearance of 2, 9 and 10.

Comment: Yes the code now reflects that and outputs [9,10,2] as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. mask means dont show the element.
2. mask = 0 means show element
3. In beginning assume all are unmasked
4. one by one check if there is intersection with next and if so, mask that
5. If something is masked, dont use it for masking next elements
6. Show all unamsked element

```py
mask = np.zeros((A.shape[0],), dtype=bool)
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    if mask[i]: continue
    a = set(A[i])
    for j in range(i+1, A.shape[0]):
        if not a.intersection(A[j]): continue
        mask[j] = True
A[~mask]
```